# VSCode with git submodules gives errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-submodules

I'm getting some errors in a project using submodules:
[image]

I think this is blocking extensions from working. I have the following extensions installed:
- haskelly
- gitlens

(the error was happening before I had gitlens installed)

I'm using a mac.

Answer (score 1):

Code 128 -> I think, the problem is with Your ssh key. Make a new one and please upload to your git config provider (gitlab etc.).

Comment: Did You set up You name and email address in config file?
`git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"`

Comment: Yep! Looks ok when I run `git config --list`