# VSCode Haskelly error

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use VSCode with the extension `Haskelly` to work with `haskell`. When I select a word, right click and choose "Go to definition" or "Peek definition" it displays `No definition found for ...`.

In the console I see the following error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Have you followed [the installation instructions](https://github.com/haskelly-dev/Haskelly#installation)? Specifically, have you run `stack build intero` in your code directory?

Comment: Yep! (Now I have a regression to this error anyway, probably about time to give up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949355/vscode-with-git-submodules-gives-errors/51949599?noredirect=1#comment90858320_51949599)